# Can I use Hyphen with adjective separately?

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure, word-order, hyphen

I know that hyphen can be used with compound words in these ways:

**Regional- und Landplanung**

or

with adjective in this way:

**regional-ländliche Planung**

but can I use hyphen with adjective in this way separately and "und" in between?

**Regional- und ländliche Planung**

English translation
(**regional and rural planning**)

Comment: Yes. That's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what precisely you're trying to say.

> Regional- und ländliche Planung

unpacks into

> Regionalplanung und ländliche Planung

which is *probably* the same as

> regionale Planung und ländliche Planung

but might not be (if it's a fixed technical term in your context).

Therefore you may want to avoid truncation markers in this instance. It is perfectly fine to co-ordinate two adjectives with 'und', so just stick to

> regionale und ländliche Planung

Answer (score 2):

If *Regionalplanung* and *regionale Planung* have exactly the same meaning, then it would be preferrable to bring both to similar forms like Killian Foth already suggested:

> regionale (Planung) und ländliche Planung

because this would be the better style.

If, however, one of these terms is a technical term with an exactly defined meaning and the other one is not (or perhaps even has a different meaning), then you can indeed write

> Regional- und ländliche Planung.

Such construction is not used very often, but it is possible.

Comment: Thank you so much Kilian, Volker and Olafant

Answer (score 1):

> Regionalplanung und regionale Planung

are not the same. While Regionalplanung is the planing about the developoment of a region, "regionale Planung" is the planning happens within the region. Regionalplanung might be performed by people e.g. in the capital city.

There are terms, which can be found as names of departments or university-degrees and sound like fitting better

> Stadt- und Raumplanung
>
> Stadt- und Regionalentwicklung

Both names cover topics like designation of the usage of areas; infrastructure or the planing of educational facilities.